# AWS glue pyspark - converting one row from source table to multiple rows in destination

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, explode

I have the below requirement

[image]

How can I achieve this using pyspark explode function

Answer (score 0):

@Mohammad Murtaza Hashmi 
In need of your help again.

```
F.split(F.concat_ws(',',*(x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('daily_qty'))),',')
```

I am not getting how to modify the above to satisfy the below requirement.

[image]

Currently destination table looks like below which is wrong
[image]